# JS - React : adding/delete from favorites

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am a beginner in react, and currently, I am trying to implement an "add / delete system" to a list of favorites.
I would like my button which is inside a "map" to be displayed in yellow when the element concerned is already in the list of favorites, or in gray when it is not in the favorites list.
My code looks like this:

```
favoriteList is an array
...
elements.map(
      element =>
        !element.isOpen && (
          <div className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12" key={element.id}>
            {element.questions
              .slice(currentPage - 1, currentPage)
              .map((question, i) => (
                <div className="card shadow mb-4" key={question.id}>
                  <div className="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <h6 className="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
                      Question N° {currentPage} of {element.questions.length}
                    </h6>
                    <a
                      onClick={() => saveOrDeleteFavorite(element.id)}
                      title="Add to favorite"
                       //(1)
                      <i className="fas fa-star fa-sm fa-fw fa-2x"></i>
                    > .........
```

So in (1), I would like to set a different color to the star icon, regarding if "element" is already in "favoriteList" or not.
Also, the information "is already present" will be useful for the function saveOrDeleteFavorite(element.id) which I call on the click on the star.

I hope I was clear, and thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: It is really difficult to follow what's happening here. It would be better if you could separate the code into functions and let them do one specific thing. This is good practice in general too.